# mapStateToProps initial value from props, then only state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have React component that is given some props. The props are given that a mapStateToProps.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, {props}) => {
    return {
      feeds: props.feeds,
      feedEntries: props.feedEntries,
      ....
```

Once the user starts interacting with the UI, they can change the state. At this point, the component needs to update itself with `state` not `props`.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, {props}) => {
    return {
      feeds: state.feeds,
      feedEntries: state.feedEntries,
      ....
```

How do you bootstrap a `mapStateToProps` function to first use the props given to the component directly upon first load. Then following, only state it's data state?

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary to check if the state property is `undefined`, and take the `props` value accordingly:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state = {}, props) => {
    return {
      feeds: state.feeds === undefined ? props.feeds : state.feeds,
      feedEntries: state.feedEntries === undefined ? props.feedEntries : state.feedEntries,
      ....
```

If you know that the properties won't have a falsy value (false, null, 0, etc...) as a legitimate value, you can replace the ternary with [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
const mapStateToProps = (state = {}, props) => {
    return {
      feeds: state.feeds || props.feeds,
      feedEntries: state.feedEntries || props.feedEntries,
      ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I Would suggest you to take another approach, instead of interrupting with the `mapStateToProps` function flow you better get the internal values from the props, and then the values that changed by the user save on the state, your render function should support it and check if any user data has received or not

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the following..

```
export default (initProps) => {
  const combinedState = {
    ...defaultState,
    ...initProps,
  };
  return createStore(
    reducer,
    combinedState,
    applyMiddleware(logger, thunk),
  )
};
```

Created a function that wraps the createStore function.. which takes an object composed of 1). the props given to the main component (initProps) and 2). `defaultProps` — a JS object imported into this file with the default shape of the store, the init props overriding any of the values in defaultProps.

```
export default (props) => {
  const store = configStore(props);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Editor props={{ ...props }} />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

The main component is takes in props, passes those props to the config store function. The store is built using the combined object above.